# Java HashMap sorted by key insertion time - creative order

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to sort hashmap or add all keys to arraylist by creative order
For example:

```
        HashMap<String, String> map_from_file = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map_from_file.put("C", "c");
        map_from_file.put("B", "b");
        map_from_file.put("D", "d");
        map_from_file.put("A", "a");


        for (String key : map_from_file.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(key);
        }
```

Output:

```
A
B
C
D
```

I want the output to be:

```
C
B
D
A
```

Thank's for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Map<String, String> map_from_file = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        map_from_file.put("C", "c");
        map_from_file.put("B", "b");
        map_from_file.put("D", "d");
        map_from_file.put("A", "a");


        for (String key : map_from_file.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(key);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `LinkedHashMap` data structure for ordered key.

Comment: That could be a comment.